# How do I get a number of sentences using a loop (while)?

Tags: c++

I want to get some strings(sentences) from the input and save them on a map. But an error occurs.

```
int main() {
  string str_inputs;
  int num_inputs;
  int count = 0;

  cout << "Enter number of products:" << endl;
  cin >> num_inputs;
  cout << num_inputs << endl;

  cout << "Enter your products:" << endl;

  while (count < num_inputs) {
    string str_temp;
    cin.getline(str_temp, 100000);
    inputs.insert(pair<int, string>(count, str_temp));
    count++;
  }
```

"count": This is the number of sentences we want to receive as input.

Error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_istream::getline(std::string&, int)’
}

Comment: What is the error? What are all those variables declared as? [Edit] the question to include a [mre].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: @simsim Post a [mcve] including the verbatim error messages as required here please. Otherwise your question will be closed as _off-topic_.

Comment: @simsim Did you mean to call `std::getline(cin,str_temp);` instead? That makes a big difference: [1](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) [2](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you explain more? I do not understand? what difference?

Comment: @simsim That's why I put the links into my comment. You can read the different documentations of these functions yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cin.getline` [function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) takes a pointer to cstring as parameter, not an `std::string` : use a `char buffer[]` instead of a string;
As mentionned in the comments, you can also use [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) function : `std::getline(cin, str_temp)`

Comment: But it is still not stored properly on the map.

Comment: @simsim Please update the post wqith your actual code :)

Comment: @simsim You also still didn't post a [mcve] as requested for.